# Why does it show that my function returns an int when it returns a char*?

Tags: yacc, lex

**The yacc code:**

```
    %{
            #include<stdio.h>
        #include<string.h>



    %}

    %union {
                    char* dval;

            }

    %token <dval> NUM VAR
    %type <dval> E P
    %left '+' '-'
    %left '*' '/'

    %%
    statement : P {printf("\nt = %s\n \n",$1);}
              ;
    P: E
       ;

    E : E '+' E {strcpy($$,gencode($1,"+",$3));}
      | E '-' E {strcpy($$,gencode($1,"-",$3));}
      | E '*' E {strcpy($$,gencode($1,"*",$3));}
      | E '/' E {strcpy($$,gencode($1,"/",$3));}
      | '(' E ')' {strcpy($$,$2);}
      | NUM {strcpy($$,$1);}
      | VAR {strcpy($$,$1);}
      ;
    %%

**The lex code:**


   %{
            #include<stdio.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>
        #include<string.h>
            #include"y.tab.h"
        int n=0;
        char *ch="t";


    %}
    %%
    [0-9]+ {strcpy(yylval.dval,yytext); return NUM;}
    [a-z]+ {strcpy(yylval.dval,yytext); return VAR;}
    \n {return 0;}
    . {return yytext[0];}
    %%
    void yyerror(char* str)
    {
            printf("\n%s",str);
    }

    char* gencode(char *first,char *op,char *second)
    {
        char  *t;
        char x[5];
        t=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*5);

        strcpy(t, ch);
        itoa(n, x);
        strcat(t, x);        
        printf("\n%s = %s %s %s\n",t,first,op,second);
        n++;
        t[strlen(t)]='\0';

        return t;
    }

    main()
    {
            yyparse();
            return 0;
    }
```

For some reason gcc outputs the error: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default].
Where as the second argument of strcpy is the function gencode which returns a char* and not an integer.

Comment: Always use these GCC options: `-Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes` and fix all resulting warnings arising from these!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `gencode` in the beginning of the yacc file. Otherwise, the compiler sees it as undefined and assumes it returns an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `gencode` in the .y file, either in a header you `#include` or directly in the .y file.

You have a much bigger problem, in that you declare `dval` (the type used for most rules) as a `char *`, but then you never initialize it to anything before writing to it with `strcpy`, so your code will crash (or worse) when strcpy tries to write to random addresses.  You can fix this by replacing the `strcpy` calls in the lex file with `yylval.dval = strdup(yytext)` and the calls in the yacc file with just assignments to `$$` (so `$$ = gencode(`... or whatever)